# django - Use primary key as an attribute

Tags: django, django-models

This may be a lame question, but how do I use the primary key as a default value for an attribute?

This is my models.py:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    thread_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=self.pk)
```

This gives me an error:

> self is not defined

How do I go about using the pk as an attribute? Any help will be grateful. Thank you.

**Edit:**

I need to use `Thread` class as a `ForeignKey` in the other class `Message`. So I need an attribute with default value for each thread.

**Edit:**

```
class ThreadParticipant(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class MessageReadState(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    read_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: You cannot do that, you would need to make two insert queries, since id is generated by database.

Comment: But why is there no error when `thread_pk = self.pk`???

Comment: @mariodev how do I do that? Can you please show me?

Comment: `I need to use Thread class as a ForeignKey in the other class Message. So I need an attribute with default value for each thread.` - why?

Comment: To get separate message by each `thread id`. I have edited and added the full code. Please have a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need this `thread_pk = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=self.pk)` line to make your ForeignKey work. 
This part of your code:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
```

is completely fine you don't seem to need anything else.

Here is the reference on FK usage in Django: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

But if you need no other fields in `Thread` model - then simply place following:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is necessary because otherwise `syncdb` won't create a table for that model.

Docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Comment: You need to remove `thread_pk` field and add any other fields you need in that model.

Comment: actually i don't need anything there, I just need the thread's pk to reference it to the message and thread_participant

Comment: Just add `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` to your `Thread` model.

Comment: Thank you. But is there anyway that I can create a default `Thread`?

Comment: What do you actually mean by 'default'?

Comment: What I meant was, is there any way that I can create a new thread automatically when I create a new message?

Comment: I mean auto populate the Thread_id if I create a new message, or else if its a reply just use the Thread_id related to it.

Comment: You can, for example, override `Message`'s `save` method and delegate this logic to it. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods